# WPF Image Clips weirdly when resizing window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I'm having an issue with an image (native 32x32px) in my WPF window displaying oddly.

It is defined in a grid like so:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Image Margin="2" Source="/KCP Doc Manager;component/Media/Icons/if__Tick_1904674 (1).png" Height="32" Width="32"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Recently approved items:" Style="{StaticResource Heading}"/>
</Grid>
```

When the window loads my image looks like this:
[image]

Resizing the window by 1px fixes the rendering issue like so:

[image]

The behavior cycles for each pixel the window is resized.

Any idea on how I can keep the image sharp?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Stretch="None"`. If that doesn't work then try `Stretch="UniformToFill"`, and possibly even `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`.

Comment: Alas none of those work. `Stretch="None"` blew the image up for some reason, the others had no effect. Ive kind of solved the problem now by using a 48x48px image and downscaling it. Not ideal but it makes the effect barely noticeable (but still there).